# WPF Datagrid - make auto generated column(s) be required

Tags: wpf, vb.net, validation, datagrid, autogeneratecolumn

I have a datagrid in a wpf application where AutoGenerateColumns="TRUE". I would like to set some or all of them to be required and invalidate if something is missing.

I was hoping there would be something like: `dgrid.Columns(_DataTable.Columns("fname").Ordinal)`**.required** `= TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Is required used to specify that the value is required when editing a row?
Validations are not done this way...

You can take a look here http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2009/09/30/Validation-in-a-WPF-DataGrid.aspx if this is what you need.

Comment: I am looking at this, but it hasn't helped me yet. Partially because the columns are auto generated. I will keep reviewing it to see if I can glean what I need from it. It certainly looks like it will help me in other situations though.

Answer (score -1):

Handle the event

[DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn.aspx)

Comment: Okay, and then when I get the e.column what do I use to set it as required?

Comment: Based on the question I assumed Required was a Property of a DataGridColumn but it is not so I don't understand the question.

Comment: ".required" is an example of something like what I would hope existed